# issue while converting my program as pip module

Tags: python, pip

I have created a project in the following is the order of files in folders.

```
src
  -->app.py(file)
     from ALLfeatures import entities_tracking
     entities_tracking.extract()
  -->config(folder)
         -->__init__.py(file)
         -->config.json(file)
            {...
             'parser': {'folder': '/var/www/data/models'},
             ...}
  -->ALLFeatures(Folder)
       -->entities_tracking(folder)
            -->segment(folder)
                -->__init__.py(file)
                   ######
                   from ALLfeatures.config import CONFIG
                   def segment(inputs):
                        have code for this function
                   ######
                -->rulebasedextraction.py(file)
            -->__init__.py(file)
               ####
               from .segmentation import segment
               def extract(inputs):
                   have code for this function
               ###           
       -->__init.py(file)
       -->config.py(file)
          import json
          from pkgutil import get_data
          CONFIG = json.loads(get_data('config', 'config.json').decode())

       -->feature2_extractor(folder)
       -->feature3_extractor(folder)
       -->feature4_extractor(folder)
```

In the code, I am trying to extract some features based on the input text that is given. I have put paths required into a json file for my ease (inside config folder). I am trying to call the json in to a variable CONFIG in config.py. I am trying to call the CONFIG variable to whereever required.

When I am running app.py I am no problems in importing the variable where ever required and I had no issues while running the code.

I have converted the same code as pip module, assuming I can extract features just by using 'from ALLfeatures import entities_tracking' whereever required.

I have successfully installed the created pip module in the place required, but when I am trying to use 'from ALLfeatures import entities_tracking', i am getting keyerror

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/home/rdk/Projects/analyzer/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ALLfeatures/entities_tracking/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from .segmentation import segment
 File "/home/rdk/Projects/analyzer/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ALLfeatures/entities_tracking/segmentation/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
folder = CONFIG['parser']['folder']
KeyError: 'parser'
```

When I made it in to a pip module it is looking for config file. which is outside the folder. I have multiple folder in ALLfeatures similar to entities_tracking, where each will extract features of different functionality. for my programming purpose I have kept the config folder outside the ALLfeatures folder because files inside all feature*_extractor folder have access to CONFIG files and for user to have access to config file.

In such scenario how do i resolve the issue, if I want to avoid error and use like all other pip module imports we normally use ?

my set.py looks like this

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

REPO_URL = 'https://www....com/.../allfeatures.git'
DOWNLOAD_URL = REPO_URL + '/repository/master/archive.zip'

setup(name='allfeatures',
      packages=find_packages(where='src'),
      package_dir={'': 'src'},
      version='0.10.3.2',
      description='Features Extraction',
      long_description='features',
      author='Energy',
      author_email='email@email.com',
      url=REPO_URL,
      download_url=DOWNLOAD_URL,
      keywords=['x', 'y', 'z'
      ],
      classifiers=[
          "Intended Audience :: Developers", "Operating System :: OS Independent", "Programming Language :: Python",
          "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6", "Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: CPython",
          "Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: PyPy"
      ],
      install_requires=[
          'future', 'requests', 'enum34', 'bs4', 'flask', 'bs4', 'gensim', 'pyfasttext', 'nltk', 'pandas',
          'numpy', 'langid', 'fasttext', 'html2text',  
          'docprocessor>=0.3.1', 'eshelper>=0.1.6', 'locationid>=0.3.6', 'utils>=1.0.5'
      ],
      platforms=['any'])
```

Comment: We need to make sure that the data files such as `config.json` are being correctly installed alongside the Python code. Is there a copy of `config.json` at `/home/rdk/Projects/analyzer/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/config/config.json`? If not,  could you edit the question to add the content of the `setup.py` file, assuming there is one?

Comment: @sinoroc: done, i have edited in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that the packaging of the project has some issues regarding the data files, and that these data files (`config.json` in that particular case) are not correctly installed alongside the Python code.

Probably the project needs the following line in the `MANIFEST.in` file:

```
recursive-include src/config *.json
```

and the following argument to the `setup` call in `setup.py`:

```
setup(
    # ...
    include_package_data=True,
    # ...
)
```

The point is to make sure that the data files end up being installed in `site-packages` alongside the project's code. In this one particular case, there should be a file `/home/rdk/Projects/analyzer/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/config/config.json` after installing the project with for example `python setup.py install` or `pip install .`.

Comment: To add to this, `package_data={'package': ['subdir/*.json']}` needed to be added to `setup.py` for me too, took like 2-3 hours to get it working correctly lol.

Comment: I believe `package_data` is not necessary in this case, since `include_package_data` is set. If I understood correctly `package_data` is used for files that are not available in the `sdist` but should be made available in the `bdist` (and thus installed). Unless instructed otherwise with `exclude_package_data`, if `include_package_data` is set, then everything that is in the `sdist` (see `MANIFEST.in`) will be added to the `bdist` (and then installed).

Comment: Thinking back I have a feeling it may have been in my case. I seem to remember that `MAINFEST.in` defines what extra to zip up, which can include the readme/license. Then, when pip installing, the `package_data` tells it which of the extra files to unzip, but only does it when `include_package_data` is set. Like I said I'm not really sure, just making the assumption as it failed to unzip any files until I added a correctly formatted `package_data`.

Comment: The whole thing is confusing. There is way too much incorrect advice all around. And there is an issue that leads to inconsistent results, because `egg-info` is not properly regenerated. At some point I took the time to test as many combinations as I could and ended up with [this summary](https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/package_data.html). I should add that what goes in `package_data` is usually the files that are not in the source code (_git_ repository) but still should be installed, so basically files that are created during say `python setup.py build` or similar build step.

Comment: Your summary would have literally saved me hours of trial and error haha. Other than `package_dir` as I had no src folder, that's pretty much what I ended up with, had a very similar folder structure.